# vue 3 reactive/computed nested variable string

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm facing an issue with reactive data in vue3 new composition api, here is what i'm trying to do

Setup

```
const imagesStyles = computed(() => {
  return { 'transform': `scale(${scale.value}) rotate(${rotation.value})` }
});
```

Template :

```
 <img
              :key="index"
              :src="images[index]"
              :style="imagesStyles" />
```

however, even if the value of `rotation/scale`, the `transform` property do not change inside the styles, but if i change color value its working flawlessly on the tag style

But what more weird, is that i tried to debug using `{{imageStyles}}` to show its value directly as text inside html, and its updating correctly.

do you have any idea why that is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED --

Always check that there is no missing units in your css property because its won't update if so

it was missing the `deg` unit so when rotate value was `0` its was working, but as soon as it change, it don't render anymore